# How do I solve $\frac{d}{dt}x(t)+3x(t)=\sin(2t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x(t)+3x(t)=\sin(2t)$?

This is the first-order linear differential equations. It has form: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x(t)+p(t)=q(t)$.

I used to solve it $x(t)=e^{-\int p(x)\,\mathrm dx}(C+\int q(x)e^{\int p(x)}\,\mathrm dx)$.

But now it takes too long. Is there any faster way?

Comment: If you have ICs at zero, the Laplace transform is fast. But this is correct. Just because a method takes too long doesn't mean it's bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt}x(t)+3x(t)=\sin(2t)\to x^{'}+3x=\sin(2t)$$
Let us find general solution for homogeneous part:
$$
x^{'}+3x=0\to x_g=C_1e^{-3t}
$$
Then, find particular solution for nonhomogeneous part in form $x_p=C_2\sin(2t)+C_3\cos(2t)$:
$$
2C_2\cos(2t)-2C_3\sin(2t)+3C_2\sin(2t)+3C_3\cos(2t)=\sin(2t)\to\\
\begin{cases}
2C_2+3C_3=0\\
3C_2-2C_3=1
\end{cases}\to C_2=\frac{3}{13},C_3=-\frac{2}{13}
$$
Solution of initial equation: $x = x_g+x_p$
$$
x=C_1e^{-3t}+\frac{3}{13}\sin(2t)-\frac{2}{13}\cos(2t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the derivative of $z:=x e^{3t}$ is $\dot z=(\dot x+3x)e^{3t}$.
Once you solve $\dot z = e^{3t}\sin 2t$, you also find $x$, so
$$x(t)=e^{-3t}\cdot\left(\int_0^te^{3\tau}\sin 2\tau\,\mathrm d\tau+C\right) $$
That integral calls for integration by parts.

Comment: Why is inside integral $e^{-3x}$ ?

Comment: @MissJune Oops, sorry, sign mistake

Comment: Why using tau and defined integral? To avoid having another C or?

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you have learned:

$\frac {dx}{dt} + 3x = sin 2t$

Integrating factor $e^\int 3 dt = e^3t$

$e^{3t} \frac {dx}{dt} + 3e^{3t}x = e^{3t}\sin 2t\\
\int (e^{3t} \frac {dx}{dt} + 3e^{3t}x) dx = \int e^{3t}\sin 2t \;dt\\
e^{3t} x = \int e^{3t}\sin 2t \;dt$

Now you can do integration by parts twice to resolve that integral.

You can use Euler's identity to say  $\int e^{3t}\sin 2t = Im \int e^{(3+2i)t} dt$ but you probably haven't learned that yet.

But, here is something else for you to put into your tool kit.

The method of undetermined coefficients.

$x= x_g + x_p$ where $x_g$ is the general solution and $x_p$ is the particular solution.

To find $x_g$ solve the easier equation of:
$\frac {dx_g}{dt} + 3x_g = 0$

Which you may know: 
$x_g = C e^{-3t}$

Or, if you didn't you could apply the integrating factor and get there quickly enough.

For $x_p$, I say it is a reasonable guess that $x_p = A \sin 2t + B \cos 2t$

How can I say that?  When we differentiate $x_p$ we will get another function in the same form and $\frac{dx_p}{dt} + 3x_p$ will be of the same form still.  Then we find $A, B$ such that everything balances.

$\frac{dx_p}{dt} = -2B \sin2t + 2A \cos 2t\\
\frac{dx_p}{dt}+3x_p = (3A-2B) \sin2t + (2A+3B) \cos 2t\\
3A-2B = 1\\
2A + 3B = 0$

And that is a system of linear equations you learned how to solve in algebra.

$x = C e^{-3t} + \frac {3}{13} \sin 2t - \frac {2}{13} \cos 2t$